# Why can't I specify Timeout per request for HttpClient?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, timeout, httpclient

Actually the question is: why is HttpClient implemented in the way that we can set Timeout property only for the whole HttpClient rather then on per-request basis?

Here is my use case:

- I have an application that makes requests to different external servers
- Requests to different servers might need to have different read Timeout values
- I would like to be able to configure timeout value for each enpoint dynamically and read it on each request. Although this value will change rarely.
- I would like to make use of connection pooling so I need to cache HttpClient and not create new one on each request

Provided that I have different Timeout values for different endpoints, I need to have separate HttpClients. One for each endpoint.

Now the question: what is the reason behind the fact that we can set Timeout value for the whole HttpClient instance?

My initial thoughts were that this is related that Timeout is a property of tcp connection that is created behind the HttpClient and can be set only for the whole connection. But after investigation of decompiled sources of HttpClient I found that Timeout is set like following:

```
private void SetTimeout(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
  if (!(this.timeout != HttpClient.infiniteTimeout))
    return;
  cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(this.timeout);
}
```

And I could not find any other uses except this one. Setting timeout to CancellationTokenSource doesn't seem to be related to tcp connection in any way and CancellationTokenSource  itself is being created for each request.

Any ideas and insights are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Well at the method level GetAsync() for example accepts a cancellation token so that allows different timeouts for request run on the same client instance.

Comment: Create your own client that inherits the HttpClient.  Then set timeout in new class.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, but the question is why HttpClient is designed in that way at all. I believe there should be some reason why you can't specify Timeout on per-request basis since it was not designed that way in the first place.

Comment: The timeout is a parameter in the transport layer which is the socket.  The HttpClient is the Application layer.  You have Client at the socket layer and Client/Server at the Application Layer.  It is sometimes confusing to have clients at different layers that have different definitions.